# Read a method's inner calling method names from 'MethodInfo' Class using reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, system.reflection

I was reading all properties and methods from a class using reflection. So i want to identify a method's inner calling methods using reflection. I tried to read MethodBody using 'GetMethodBody()' method. But it is listing only local variables. So could you please help on this?

Comment: "Inner calling methods"? Please give an example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get method calls from `MethodInfo` by reflection.

Method calls are just an `IL` instruction, from the reflection point of view all is just `IL`. There is no difference between instruction that load argument and instruction that call method.

But, you still can do that in some ways.

1. You can use `Roslyn` to go over your method and search for invocation nodes.
2. You can get the `IL` from `MethodBody`, parse it, and search for `call` or `callvirt` instruction, then you need to resolve the operand (`token` in our case) and get the method. This is not easy way but you can use some ILReader libraries to handle it.

**Update:**

With Roslyn, you have more than one way to do that.

You can take your method as `MethodDeleration` and call to `DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()`.

You can create a custom `CSharpSyntaxWalker` and override `VisitInvocationExpression` and you do the same but with `CSharpSyntaxRewriter`.

For your needs you don't need to rewrite something so you need to choice between `DescendantNodes` (the straight forward way) and `CSharpSyntaxWalker` (the more elegant and powerful way).

You have a lot of examples here in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roslyn) and all over the web. Take a look at [Josh Varty](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/learn-roslyn-now/) series about Roslyn. Also the [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) page is a good resource. Two must use tools is [Quoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) and [TryRoslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGAbzxg5kNIpgDcA9mAAmMALIAKAJSt2nAL555QA==). Also check [SyntaxVisulaizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.NETCompilerPlatformSDK) for VS.

The IL parsing way is more complicated (but not so much).
As I wrote the procedure to do that, is call to `GetILAsByteArray()` then you need to parse the bytes to find call instruction and then to take the instruction operand and resolve is token.

For all of this you can use some existing IL Reader like [this](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/01/00/37/88/ILReader.zip) or [this](https://github.com/DmitryGaravsky/ILReader) and when you figureout the requested instructions, you need to call `yourModule.ResolveMethod` that return you a method base. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148297/resolving-the-tokens-found-in-the-il-from-a-dynamic-method) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17734670/986184) for examples

Comment: Can you provide any links or examples about this?